# Как мне сделать так, чтобы если в файлах есть различия, то скрипт заканчивал работу?

Tags: bash, diff

У меня есть скрипт который сравнивает два файла.

```bssh
#!/bin/bash

for ((t = 1; t <= $1; t++))
do
    ./test
    ./correct
    ./main
    diff output1 output2
    echo $t
done
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы если в файлах есть различия, то скрипт заканчивал работу?

Comment: можете воспользоваться командой exit.

Comment: Exit то я могу сделать, а вот как узнать нашел ли diff отличия я не понимаю

Comment: Если нужно просто определить, что какие-то различия есть, то вместо `diff` лучше вызывать `cmp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Команда `diff` возвращает статус `1`, если файлы
различаются.  Так что:

```sh
diff output1 output2 || exit $?
```

Или, чтобы выйти из цикла, но не из программы:

```sh
diff output1 output2 || break
```

Comment: возможно стоило бы упомянуть о break, для выхода из цикла

Comment: @PotroNik  Добавил.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh -efu` тоже поможет :)